# Dividing a list of files with constraints

Tags: algorithms

I don't know if a solution to this problem is too complicated to figure out, but I've been banging my head on it for a couple weeks, so I'm hoping for an outside point of view.

I have a list of 88 files today from different sources:
Alpha sent 9 files.
Beta sent 7 files.
Gamma sent 19 files.
Delta sent 13 files.
Epsilon sent 20 files.
Zeta sent 20 files.

I need to divide them up between Ann, Bob, Charley, and Ren.

Ren always gets all the files from Delta, but can receive more.
There are a couple processors that have assigned customers, while everyone else just assigned to a processor at random.

Ann can only get 15 files today.
This is an example of a processor with a max file limit. Say someone has other projects they are working on, or is recovering from being sick, or has family stuff going on, or whatever, and their manager decides to give them a lighter load. Instead of dividing them evenly among all 4 and then have to reassign work after the fact they can set the limit ahead of time.

The main question is how do I divide them up as evenly as possible, so Ann gets 15, and the other 3 get close to the same amount?
"Close to the same amount" means to divide it as evenly as possible, with any remainder passed out to someone, so in the example Bob got 25, while Charley and Ren got 24, because 73/3 = 24 with a remainder of 1.

The optimal solution that I worked out manually for this data set was:
Ann: 15 files
Bob: 25 files.
Charley: 24 files.
Ren: 13 Delta files, and 11 additional files, bringing her total to 24.

The variables are the number of files, the number of people who get files, and the maximum number that they can each receive.
Also, left out to remove some complexity, but Ren ALWAYS gets all the files from Delta, even if she has the day off, but she won't get any other files in that instance.

Comment: On a side note, I broke Chat GPT with this question, in that as I was working through the problem trying to get it to give an answer that wasn't completely wrong, it stopped responding, and throws an error when I try to pull up that chat log...

Comment: With one division found differing by 1 where more isn't inevitable, what are you actually asking? How to divide by "number of unconstrained persons"?

Comment: 1. How do you define "close to the same amount"?  What is the objective function you are trying to optimize?  2. Why does it matter who sent the files or who the source was?  The source seems irrelevant (except for the constraint that Ren gets at least 13 files).  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @D.W. "close to the same amount" you can't evenly divide 10 by 3, so one person gets 4, and two people get 3, but they are close. Because of the assigned files and max limits, I'm having trouble finding a solution where someone doesn't end up with 10 extra. (2) one to clarify that files come from different places, and that it can matter, and if possible they want me to try to pass them out by source, so Ann might get all of Alpha and 6 of Beta, instead of passing them out at random. (3) I'm new here, should I put in my existing function? I didn't want to bias anything one way or another.

Comment: @greybeard Maybe? Sorry, I'm new here, so still trying to figure out how the community works. The number of files in a day can be 100-500, but ranges around 250 most days. We have 8 employees who regularly get files, but sometimes they go on vacation. Two of the employees have designated customers at the moment, but it's more than one each, and those customers don't send files every day. It's a complexity fractal, so I was trying to simplify it down to the elements that seem to matter for the problem. Again sorry if I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: (Currently, there are tags `operations-research` for statistics and math at stackexchange.com.) (There is a nascent site [Operations Research](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research-and-analytics).)(I'm actually fond of *single queue, multiple workers* systems. In real life, there are *setup times* (such as recollecting peculiarities with any given customer).)

Comment: So "close to the same amount" means there is some X so that everyone gets either X or X+1?  Except for Ann, where it doesn't matter what Ann gets or how different Ann's number is from everyone else?  Can you be more precise, and then [edit] the question to state the problem precisely?  It would help if you could state the general condition for a proposed solution to be correct, rather than just giving an example and forcing us to guess what the general rule is.  I don't know what you mean by someone ending up "with 10 extra".

Comment: @D.W. I added in a bit more. I'm thinking I might make a pseudocode version of my code that is almost working. I'm hanging out in the CS chat room for a while too.

Comment: @greybeard SO.SE really didn't like this as an [operations-research] question. -2 votes, 2 close votes, 0 comments to tell me why. I deleted it instead.

Comment: @greybeard Oh, sorry; Stack Overflow I mean. I thought that's where you were saying to that the Operations-Research might be a good place to ask the question.

Comment: (umm - no. While I missed the existing [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), I mentioned tag `operations-research` in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operations-research) ("uses mathematical and statistical methods to improve efficiency") and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("applying appropriate analytical methods to help those who run organisations make better decisions").) See each site's *How do I ask a Good Question?*

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT: some more information".  Instead, revise the question based on the feedback you've received, so it reads well and is clear for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Comment: @D.W. Understood. Hopefully I did it right this time.

Comment: @D.W. I might have cracked my problem finally, though I need to test it more, and I'm actually not sure which is best; post real code as an answer, post pseudo code or a walkthrough of the steps as an answer, or just delete the question outright...

Comment: @AndyD273, our purpose is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  So, the best is to find a way to articulate your question in a general way so it is likely to be something relevant to others, and so they can find it via search, and then post an answer, with explanations, concepts, and pseudocode.  We're not a coding site, so an answer that is just a block of code is usually not well-received here.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought and trial and error, this is the solution that I believe solves my problem:

1. Get list of processors that are selected to get files with the limit they are allowed to receive, and their current count initialized at 0.
2. Get a list of all designated processors and file sources.
3. Loop through the list of files and see if each one needs to be assigned to a designated processor. If so put it in their queue, subtract one from their allowed limit, and add 1 to their current count.  If not then put the file in a file queue to be passed out.
4. Calculate the rolling average that each processor should receive by dividing the file queue count by the number of processors.
5. While there are still files in the queue, and processors that still haven't reached their max:
   a. Loop through the list of processors sorted by their allowed limit ascending.
   b. Dequeue a file and give it to the processor, subtract 1 from allowed limit, add 1 to current count.
   c. check to see if they have reached the rolling average or their allowed limit. If so go to next processor, else go to next file.
6. Once all processors have reached the rolling average, if there are still files to be passed out, and if there are any processors that haven't reached their limit, then re-calculate the rolling average, adding the total to the original total. Go to 5.

Pseudo code:

```
For each selected processor
    SelectedProcessorList.Add with ID, FileLimit, CurrentCount = 0

Get list of DesignatedProcessors and Sources
For each file 
    If the file Source belongs to a DesignatedProcessor
        Assign to DesignatedProcessor
        Add 1 to CurrentCount
        Subtract 1 from FileLimit
    Else
        FileStack.Enqueue(file)
Next file

RollingAverage = FileStack count / SelectedProcessorList count

While FileStack count > 0 and SelectedProcessorList(with FileLimit > 0) count > 0
    For each Processor in SelectedProcessorList Order by FileLimit
        While FileStack count > 0
            File = FileStack.Dequeue
            Assign File to Processor
            Add 1 to CurrentCount
            Subtract 1 from FileLimit
            If Processor CurrentCount >= RollingAverage Or Processor FileLimit < 1 Then 
                Exit While
        Loop While
    Next Processor
    If all Processors have been assigned work, And any Processor has a FileLimit > 0 then
        RollingAverage += Math.Ceiling(FileStack count / SelectedProcessorList(Where FileLimit > 0) count)
Loop While
```